# Able to see image on browser, but urllib.urlretrieve() fails to downlad it. How can I download it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

Image path --> http://markinternational.info/data/out/366/221983609-black-hd-desktop-wallpaper.jpg

Code I am using

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("https://markinternational.info/data/out/366/221983609-black-hd-desktop-wallpaper.jpg" , "photu.jpg")
```

What it returns (returns same thing for successful or unsuccessful attempts)

```
('photu.jpg', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7fe3cfb27d88>)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You have an issue with the image host. They seem to prevent downloading the image from non-browser clients.

`Access denied | markinternational.info used Cloudflare to restrict access`

Comment: How will I go about solving this issue. Is there way I can make them not know that I am machine? @Sazzy

Comment: How did you get this log by the way @Sazzy

Comment: Do @Rakesh method, and view the content of the photu.jpg file.

Comment: I did it. I got 3.3 kb photu.jpg and after opening, got the error, Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x21) COuld not load image @Sazzy

Comment: Look at it in a text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fake the user-agent to bypass this restriction by the web server.

I used Python3 and `requests` library, I managed to get the picture:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://markinternational.info/data/out/366/221983609-black-hd-desktop-wallpaper.jpg'
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('photo.jpg', 'wb') as W:
    W.write(res.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
import urllib
f = open('photu.jpg','wb')
f.write(urllib.urlopen('https://markinternational.info/data/out/366/221983609-black-hd-desktop-wallpaper.jpg').read())
f.close()
```

Comment: Still same result, no image being downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sending a raw http request without any `User-Agent` header, the server is not allowing the request to pass through. You can mock it with a defined `User-Agent` in header and it'll work as if it works on browser.

```
url = "https://markinternational.info/data/out/366/221983609-black-hd-desktop-wallpaper.jpg"

req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as img_file:
    img_file.write(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read())
```